# Pandas Dataframe, how to count every time values for each column go above or below a threshold of two numbers

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, counter

I have a data frame like this:

```
    account1    account2    account3    account4
0   4.730500    18.899000   5.926950    3.548100
1   3.922000    11.609333   4.405667    5.333333
2   5.172667    12.932667   4.772167    5.500000
3   4.429833    10.694667   4.859500    8.36100
4   5.149167    13.496667   8.451045    5.166667
5   2.598000    10.655500   5.952333    4.833333
6   5.805167    15.418000   5.296167    4.450000
7   4.168833    9.624833    5.436333    4.403333
8   4.452750    14.699750   4.757250    4.896000
```

I have three groups defined by the thresholds of 4 and 7 that each point could be a part of. I would like to count every time rows in a column move across a threshold and into a new group (below 4, above 4, above 7, or below 7).

For example account 1 changes groups:

| index | groupchange |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 0 |
| 4 | 0 |
| 5 | 1 |
| 6 | 1 |
| 7 | 0 |
| 8 | 0 |

So account1 changes group 4 times

I'd like the output to be a data frame like:

```
    account1          account2       account3        account4
0   4                 0              2               3
```

I tried to change the values for points  to a distinct group name like:

```
df[df < 4]= 0
df[(df >= 4) & (df <=7)] = 1
df[df > 7]= 2
```

So then I have a data frame like this:

```
    account1    account2    account3    account4
0   1.0         2.0         1.0         0.0
1   0.0         2.0         1.0         1.0
2   1.0         2.0         1.0         1.0
3   1.0         2.0         1.0         2.0
4   1.0         2.0         2.0         1.0
5   0.0         2.0         1.0         1.0
6   1.0         2.0         1.0         1.0
7   1.0         2.0         1.0         1.0
8   1.0         2.0         1.0         1.0
```

And then to do some apply function to count occurrences of consecutive row values not matching like:
`df.apply(lambda x : sum(x.iloc[-1:] != x.shift(-1).iloc[1:]))`

This obviously doesn't work and I'm sure this is an elegant solution that can skip converting values to 1,2,3.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Can you check the output for `account3`. I found 2, not 1: groups 1 -> 2 and 2 -> 1 (index 3, 4, 5)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost there!. Use [`pd.cut`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.cut.html) to simplify your conditions and [`diff`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.diff.html) to check if the group has changed or not. Count only rows where the difference is not equal to 0 (new group):

```
def group_changes(sr):
    bins = [-np.inf, 4, 7, np.inf]
    groups = pd.cut(sr, bins=bins, labels=False)
    return groups.diff().fillna(0).ne(0).sum()

out = df.apply(group_changes)
```

Output:

```
>>> out
account1    4
account2    0
account3    2
account4    3
dtype: int64
```

Details for `account1`:

```
bins = [-np.inf, 4, 7, np.inf]
pd.concat({'cut': (out := pd.cut(df['account1'], bins=bins, labels=False)),
           'diff': (out := out.diff().fillna(0)),
           'fillna': (out := out.ne(0))},
          axis=1)

# Output
   cut  diff  fillna
0    1   0.0   False
1    0  -1.0    True
2    1   1.0    True
3    1   0.0   False
4    1   0.0   False
5    0  -1.0    True
6    1   1.0    True
7    1   0.0   False
8    1   0.0   False
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work as well:

```
df.clip(4,7).ne(df).diff().ne(0).cumsum().sub(1).max().to_frame().T
```

Output:

```
   account1  account2  account3  account4
0         4         0         2         3
```

Comment: Your idea to use `clip` here is very clever for this case (even if I prefer to use `pd.cut` for more threshold). Brilliant :)

Comment: This mostly works, but spot checking a few accounts, a few are not what I would manually count. As the other answer works, I am not going to look into why. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: @Corralien thank you for saying that! Your answers have always taught me a lot :)